# Combining categories in charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, combine, pivot-chart

How do I combine "Chicken", "Moose" and "Pork" into one "Meat"-name, and the remainders into just "Seafood"?

I would also want to show how much of the "meat" and "seafood" are "fresh" and "frozen"?

[image]

Comment: Be advised that you are treading on thin ice, terminology-wise. Some people believe that fish *is* meat.  Other people believe that poultry (e.g., chicken) is *not* meat.  Some people feel as strongly about this as they do about religious issues.

Comment: @Blackwood: Thanks for embedding the image.  But, when you do that, please make the image link to itself, as I have done in my edit.

Comment: Thanks @Scott. Can you explain the difference, or point me to an explanation?

Comment: The difference is that, the way I did it, a reader can click on the displayed image (which is typically scaled down to 640 pixels wide to fit in the Super User text area) and go directly to the image on imgur.com (which, in this case, is over 1000 pixels wide).  Or, more usefully, Ctrl+click to open the image in a new tab.  (Some browsers have features that let you do this, but not all.) The idea is discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189343/195817 "Images should be automatically rescaled and the full size linked"), although it might not be as clear and up to date as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

To get a chart showing “meat” vs. “seafood”,
you will probably need to have a separate range
that shows just those two categories. 
You won't need to *maintain* the data separately;
just use `SUM` or `SUMIF` formulas.

You might also be able to do something
with a PivotTable and/or a PivotChart. 
I'm not sufficiently familiar with those to give an answer;
probably somebody else will.

Once you create your “meat” vs. “seafood” chart,
there are multiple ways of displaying multiple data series
(e.g., “fresh” vs. “frozen”). 
I suggest a “Stacked Column” chart.

Comment: Well? Any results?

Comment: I was able to sort it out like you said. However, I guess there are other, perhaps easier ways of doing it. Anyway, thanks for helping out!